# Cannot open Nuclide

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I followed the instructions to install Nuclide on top of Atom:
https://nuclide.io/docs/quick-start/getting-started/

However, after installing Nuclide, closing atom, and reopening atom - only atom is showing - Nuclide welcome screen does not show.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i just loaded nuclide from within atom. When i reopen atom there is a home tab which displays nuclide welcome screen.

Comment: did you load nuclide from atom?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Nuclide was loaded in a different tab. The default tab still said "welcome to Atom" so it was misleading